# JavaScript - Count Number of Visitor for Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript, How do i increment the number whenever the page is refreshed on the browser. Client Implementation only :)

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="CounterVisitor">
          <span class="counter-item">0</span>
          <span class="counter-item">0</span>
          <span class="counter-item">1</span>
          <span class="counter-item">1</span>
          <span class="counter-item">8</span>
          <span class="counter-item">4</span>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var counter = 001184;
var newnum = 001184 + 1;

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("counter-item");
el.innerHTML = newnum;
```

This is how the result will look like when i refresh the browser, but it is static for now.

[image]

Comment: do you fetch the number from the server or is it pure client side?

Comment: you need a server side language to save the last visitor number

Comment: I just started a random number on my own.

Comment: I dont think javascript is necessary here. You need a backend implementation for this,

Comment: I just want the number to increment to the html page using js only that's all

Comment: So If I understand you don't want the server implementation, but the client js implementation just to play around?

Comment: @Suresh - This is impossible. You are suppose to save it somewhere in DB or `file system` and display it in UI...

Comment: Yup client implementation only :)

Comment: @Suresh thats gonna be static. You just want when the user enters your page it will be `001185`. If you refresh the page, it will still `001185`. Right?

Comment: @Eddie Everytime i refresh the page it will increment by 1

Comment: @Suresh Then that is not possible using `js` only. Unless you use `cookies`, which will only increment on that specific device/browser.

Comment: well, you can give a cookie with the number and then, every reload increase it by one. you can do the same tick with local storage

Comment: What is the server architecture?  Counting visitors is something the server would do and provide the client with the information to display.

Answer (score 3):

In that case you can use `localStorage` to keep the count in your browser.

```
<div id="CounterVisitor">
</div>

<script>
var n = localStorage.getItem('on_load_counter');

if (n === null) {
  n = 0;
}
n++;

localStorage.setItem("on_load_counter", n);

nums = n.toString().split('').map(Number);
document.getElementById('CounterVisitor').innerHTML = '';
for (var i of nums) {
  document.getElementById('CounterVisitor').innerHTML += '<span class="counter-item">' + i + '</span>';
}

</script>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e2q8j1q4/55/

Comment: Check the above fiddle demo,

Comment: This only keeps track of the user's visits, not the total number of visits.

Comment: Yes, you cannot track total number of visits without the backend implementation or a server.

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrate following.

- How to check *number of times* visitor has visited this website
- How to *show the count*

using

```
incrementAndShowValue();

function incrementAndShowValue() {
  var value = getCookie("visitcounter") || 0;
  var newValue = ("00000" + (Number(value) + 1)).slice(-6);
  var container = document.getElementById("counterVisitor");
  String(newValue).split("").forEach(function(item, index) {
    container.children[index].innerHTML = item;
  });
  counter++;
  setCookie("visitcounter", counter);
}
```

**Note** : You need to **test this locally** since it will not work with sandboxed frames like **stack-snippets**, **fiddle**, etc.

**Demo**

```js
incrementAndShowValue();

function incrementAndShowValue() {
  var value = getCookie("visitcounter") || 0;
  var newValue = ("00000" + (Number(value) + 1)).slice(-6);
  var container = document.getElementById("counterVisitor");
  String(newValue).split("").forEach(function(item, index) {
    container.children[index].innerHTML = item;
  });
  counter++;
  setCookie("visitcounter", counter);
}

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires = "";
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=https://stacksnippets.net/js";
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
.counter-item {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

#incrementCounter {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counterVisitor">
  <span class="counter-item">0</span>
  <span class="counter-item">0</span>
  <span class="counter-item">0</span>
  <span class="counter-item">0</span>
  <span class="counter-item">0</span>
  <span class="counter-item">0</span>
</div>

<button id="incrementCounter">Increase Count</button>
```

Comment: It will increment by page refresh,not a button

Comment: @Suresh Try the updated code, but you need to test this locally.